# Help with installing jre-8u101-linux-x64

Tags: java, tar, javafx

I want to install the proprietary version of java. Thus, I went to their website and followed their instructions here http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml.

Quite simply it says to:

1. change directory to the one you want Java installed on. I went to **/usr/bin/java**.
2. then I unpacked the tarball with this command - `sudo tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Note: When the installation has completed you will see the word **Done**.

Doh! I didn't see the word **Done**. When I unpacked the tarball the files seemed to be put in place of the directory I unpacked them in, but I don't think Java was "installed". In the past, I knew Java had to be uninstalled before a newer version could be installed and I did just that. So, I tried checking my java version.

`java -version`

> The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
>
> - default-jre
> - gcj-5-jre-headless
> - openjdk-8-jre-headless
> - gcj-4.8-jre-headless
> - gcj-4.9-jre-headless
> - openjdk-9-jre-headless
>
> Try: sudo apt install

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Please don't add "ANSWERED" to the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Answer (score 2):

**Webupd8team** has made a very good job in preparing installation packages for the official oracle java.  You can follow these three steps and install it correctly and add the webupd8team update server to your system so that a new java is installed whenever it's released automatically.

1. Add the server by typing: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`.
2. Update your system: `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Install both `oracle-java8-installer` and `oracle-java8-set-default` by typing: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default`.
4. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Recently Oracle has moved it's archives, because of that webupd8team/java is not wokring. They need to update the bundle location. Meanwhile, you can follow the below method to install java on any linux machine.

https://watchmouse.blogspot.in/2018/01/how-to-set-javahome-for-java.html